# Non-Renewing Subscription: turn back time

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, icloud

I'm creating an app that will unlock features to users for a limited time. Premium features let's call them. They can buy a subscription for a month, 6 months or a year. These subscriptions would be non-renewing. After a lot of searching the web and finding very different "solutions", I turn to StackOverflow for what the best should be.

When a subscription is bought, the end date is stored locally on the device until synced via iCloud, because Apple wants you to have this subscription on all your devices. The app checks iCloud to see if the current subscription is still available, shows a nice countdown for the users with days left. But I'm currently encountering a problem. When the user has paid for a month, and changes the date of the device to a year earlier (or something else), it can use the subscription for a year. The countdown now doesn't show 23 days left, but 389.

How can I avoid this?
Should I check a certain server to check for the real time and date?
What if a user only uses the app in airplane mode?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check standard web-based time-servers to do this. Since I have my own server (as part my in-app purchase mechanisms), I just ask my server for the current time, at the server. I do this every time the app launches, and every time I make a server-call (usually when in-app purchases are done). I then store the time locally (either in the KeyChain or NSUserDefaults, can't remember which!), and use it (and the device time, which ever is later in time) to compute purchase expiries.

Of course, this assumes that the user has a network connection when they launch the app. You can only do so much though!

Answer (score -1):

Actually what happening is after successful completion of your InAppPurchase apple will provide you a Transaction Reciept...this transaction reciept is stored in locally . When you want to check the subscription is in  active or expired you need to request the storekit with this transaction reciept then the store kit will give you the status .. if the status is 0 then it is in active state . if the status is 21006 then your transaction is Expired. If you want to continue the subscription in antoher device then you need to Restore the transactions there .. after completion of the restoration you will get all the product ids and the transaction reciepts.. you need to store the transaction reciepts there and you need to pass this for the storekit whether it is in active or expired state .. sorry for my poor english..

Comment: This is just wrong. Apple doesn't know anything about renewal times/dates for non-renewing subcriptions. It is up to app to implement such a mechanism for non-renewing subscriptions.